# Запуск команд асинхронно?

Tags: bat

Можно ли запустить команды асинхронно?

Тут получается так что первая команда продолжает висеть и не завершается, остальные 2 не запускаются.

```
node server
node mail_server
wiki
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запускайте еще один экземпляр `cmd` с ключом `/c` при помощи команды `start`

```
start cmd /c "node server"
start cmd /c "node mail_server"
start cmd /c wiki
```

Comment: Спасибо! 

1)  А их можно запустить в фоновом режиме? 
2) Можно ли как то проверить, что если уже запущено то не запускать (или закрыть и запустить)?

Comment: @manking что значит "в фоновом режиме"? Проверить можно. Но для начала нужно понять, что именно нужно проверять. Смотреть в сторону `tasklist`